# Rails: Where, and how, should I initialize a set of QuizAnswers in my User model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been reading the Hartl book, searching online, but I still find myself guess-working my way through learning Rails:
I'm trying to set up a short multiple-choice quiz at the start of an e-learning. Here's my User model which, amongst other things, 'has_many QuizAnswers':

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  serialize :planning_progress
  serialize :facilitation_progress
  serialize :teamwork_progress
  serialize :communication_progress

  # following used to record which roles a user is involved in
  serialize :leadership_roles

  before_create :set_progress_vars

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  validates :age, presence: { :message => ": Please choose your age" }
  validates :section, presence: { :message => ": Please choose the section you belong to"}
  has_many :posts
  has_many :quiz_answers

  private  

  # this function triggered 'before_create'
  def set_progress_vars
    self.planning_progress = [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]
    self.facilitation_progress = [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]
    self.teamwork_progress = [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]
    self.communication_progress = [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]
  end

end
```

My QuizAnswer model, so far, is this:

```
class QuizAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    attr_reader :questionID    
    def initialize(p_id)
        @questionID = p_id
    end
end
```

I'd like to know how I would set up 8 QuizAnswers with questionIDs from 0 to 7. I'm assuming this should be done in the User model, given that it's the thing that has the 'has_many' relationship.

I could add the following code to the set_progress_vars, as this is triggered when (before) a User is created:

```
8.times {
      quiz_answers.push(QuizAnswer.new)
    }
```

But is quiz_answers an Array? How do I pass an index value to each new QuizAnswer, so it can track which question it refers to?

If anyone has some code pointers, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do it in model nor controller, I would crete another object, Service or Form object depending on what do you want to do with QuizAnswers ( maybe save them to database or create form for them ).

I think that if you keep any logic for QuizAnswer in you user Model, then SRP is broken.

You can take a look at this article : http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/

But, if you really want to go down that road then:

```
def createQuizAnswers
   for i in 0...7
      quiz_answers.create(i) // to save to database && connect it to user
    end
end
```

EDIT:

First, check database schema (db/schema.rb) and see if your QuizAnswers table has user_id column. if not create migration ( rails generate migration add_user_id_to_quiz_answers , add "add_column :quiz_answers, :user_id, :integer" to first function.

Next thing, you have QuizAnswers controller for take quiz answers ( where is the question with possible answers ). On next/submit button you can take params and create for the current_user corresponding quiz answer, for instance

```
current_user.quiz_answers.create(quiz_params)
```

Then, wherever you need these answers you can call them by

```
current_user.quiz_answers
```

Let's say you need to go through answers:

```
current_user.quiz_answers.each do |qa|

end
```

In this loop you can check if the answer is correct or whatever you want. So in the end this is possible code

```
current_user.quiz_answers.each do |qa|
    if qa.correct
      current_user.points++
    end
end
```

Or maybe, as an admin, you want to go through some users and for each user check their answers:

```
users = User.where(some_condition)
users.each do |user|
   user.quiz_answers.each do |qa|
      if qa.correct
         user.points++
      end
      user.save
   end
end
```

Comment: I don't think I understand how 'instantiating' the quiz_answers in User is putting QuizAnswer logic there. Surely the User has_many QuizAnswers, so they should just be instantiated there? I'm not suggesting putting any other QuizAnswer code in User.

Comment: Yeah but thats one more reason for code to change... What if you want to add atributte? Add some logic for creation? One more thing you have to tell us what is your intent with this creation?

Comment: I'm trying to set up an 8-answer multi-choice quiz, as part of an e-learning on leadership. I'd like a user's answers to be stored, by whatever means necessary. I still don't understand how a User would access its answers if it doesn't have them instantiated as part of itself...

Comment: Okay, when you create QuizAnswers they have to have user_id as a column(foreign key to the user table). Then, you can call something like User.find(1).quiz_answers and you will get an array of quiz_answers. So for recap, you have to have column user_id, form(quiz form with answers) where you will get what user selected, save that as QuizAnswer.create!(current_user.id, other_attributes, etc). After that you will have these answers connected to the user.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and comments. I don't understand in which part of the code I should add the suggestions you make. I think I need it explained in more detail, sorry. If you could spell it out in more detail, I'd appreciate it. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. That's much clearer. When you ask 'where is the question with possible answers?' are you suggesting I should be doing something else? Initially I want to display the quiz questions, not the user's answers. I don't know how to pass a user's answer into the current_user's QuizAnswers. Is that even the right way to think about it? I also don't know how to 'take params' from the submit button - where would that happen? Sorry for all the questions, but I've been trying to solve this for a while.

Comment: When I said possible answers I meant options for answers. For instance question 1 have answers 'a','b','c' and 'd' and correct answers are 'b' and 'd'. For current_user its user that is logged, user answering questions and this will create current_users QuizAnswer. Other way could be: qa = QuizAnswer.new(quiz_params) qa.user_id = current_user.id qa.save

Comment: I'm sorry - I've re-read it, but don't understand your last comment at all. Where does the quiz_params variable come from? In which piece of code do you suggest this 'qa=QuizAnswer...' code should go?

Comment: Quiz_params are parameters from post request from your page(when you click submit). It is list of permited parameters, it should be located in the controller and defined in private part: private def quiz_params params.require(:quiz_answer).permit (stuff_you_send_via_post). The other thing you ask also belongs into QuizAnswerController in create function.

Comment: I already have a post_params function in the QuizAnswerController: It is as follows... params.require(:quiz_answer).permit(:body, :user_id) I still don't know how to display the questions. I may have to ask another question, I guess.

Comment: Okay, use post_params (not descriptive name, but ok) in QuizAnswer creation. To show question in QuestionController in show action put something like @(no space)question = Question.where(condition) or @(no space)questions = Question.all and then use @(no space)question in your show.html.erb file for question... This (no space) marks means that @(no space)question == @question, stackoverflow doesn't allow more then one of these :) Please mark answer as correct if you found it usefull :) Thanks and good luck

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I'm sure you're probably right - I just don't understand it. I don't know how the submit button 'knows' where to link to. Is it somehow 'loaded' with a pointer to somewhere? And if so, where is that set?

Comment: It is defined in routes.rb file, and when you type into console rake routes you will see all routes in your application. If you take a look into .html.erb file which contains that button you will see that exact route is called (unless its resource, google that if you stuck on that particular case). Note: you have to add _path to the routes, and you want first column from rake routes

Comment: Have you been able to resolve your issue ? Do you need any more help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66255/discussion-between-moosefetcher-and-nickcatib).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. but aren't the question ids stored in the database?

```
class User
  before_create :make_quiz_answers
  def make_quiz_answers
    (0..7).to_a.each do |question_id|
      quiz_answers.build(questionID: question_id)
    end
    true
  end
end
```

It sounds like you should have a quiz `Question` model to me where a `QuizAnswer` `belongs_to` a `Question`?

Comment: I don't know if the question ids are stored in the database. If I just add 8 quiz_answers to User, without passing each an id, how would I access the database ID?